# how to create an undirected graph using a boolean list?

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, edges

I have a list of zero's and one's.
(1's being higher than average and 0's being below average)
I am trying to make an undirected graph but I keep getting

```
test = (ustest[states] > final).astype(int)
test2 = test.unstack()#this is still a series
test3 = test2.tolist()#this is the series converted to a list


usmap = nx.Graph()
usmap = usmap.add_edges_from(test3)
```

I keep getting "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()" but I am unsure on what I am doing wrong.
I am trying to have to have this list be the edges in the graph.
***EDIT***

> File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "/Users/dshadow/Desktop/usstates.py", line 53, in 
>       usmap = usmap.add_edges_from(test3)
>
> File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py", line 857, in add_edges_from
>       ne = len(e)
>
> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: Can you add some example data, e.g. `ustest` and `final`?

Comment: ustest was a data frame with all 50 US states in the columns and rows showing data between the states and the final was the average of the entire data frame(707) which was used to create test for the boolean list.

Comment: How are you expecting your graph to look like?

Comment: I'm just looking for the right function to use to represent the flows (list of 1s and 0s) as edges. I'm not sure how to even start with this graph because i'm having problems with the edges.

Comment: the entire error message will be helpful - it will say what line of code is causing the error.

Comment: can you provide some sample entries of test 3?  I don't think it's a list of the form `[(node1, node2), (node1, node3)]`

Comment: test3 is 2601 numbers long, but i cut out a small piece [...,0,
 1,
 0,
 1,
 0,
 1,
 0,
 0,
 0,...]

Comment: But edges without nodes are, just lonely?

Comment: i have a series(the series has the states to state numbers) that came from the original ustest data frame but I am unsure on how to create a graph with it while keeping the columns connected to the rows therefore is the reason on why I went ahead with the list but I am unsure on how to create the graph with the list. I am just confused on what functions I need to create the graph.

Comment: Our point is that we have no idea what your `pd.Series` looks like. Post a sample of it so we can debug.